# Is there a compact way of telling the C# compiler to use the base Equals and == operator?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, struct, overriding, equals

I am fairly new to C#, and I come from a C++ background.

I have defined a struct, and the (Microsoft) compiler keeps popping up the error CA1815 "'GenericSendRequest' should override Equals"

I read a bit around and saw that C# structs derive from ValueType which impleents a generic Equals using reflection. This confused me more:

1. Why does the compiler create an error instead of a warning if its just a performance issue?
2. Why does it define that generic Equals in the first place if it's not going to let you use it?

So how can I tell the compiler that "I don't care"? Something similar with just declaring assignment operator in a C++ class without providing definition to acknowledge that I know what I am doing.

So far my solution has been to include:

```
    public static bool operator ==(GenericSendRequest lhs, GenericSendRequest rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(GenericSendRequest lhs, GenericSendRequest rhs)
    {
        return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    //Yes, it also makes me override GetHashCode since I'm overriding Equals.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
```

in my struct, which is just awful.

**Edit:**
This is the struct definition:

```
public struct GenericSendRequest
{
        public LiveUser             Sender;
        public LiveUser[]           Receivers;
        public Message              Msg;
        public ServiceHttpRequest   HttpRequest;
}
```

Its usage is just multiple return values from a function:

```
public static GenericSendRequest CreateGenericSendRequest(...);
```

Comment: Can you show the usage of the struct which caused the error CA1815 ?

Comment: Since structs should represent immutable values, I would probably use a class instead of a struct for the return value.  If that is all you are using the class for, you might even choose to use the Tuple class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: Tuples do not allow for modification though. I think that making it a class will be the right solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is definitely not an error, its only a warning - and that warning even only will show up if you have enabled code analysis as part of your build. It's a *suggestion* for performance optimization - take it that way.

**Edit:**

Turns out this is configurable:

Go to `Project Properties | Code Analysis |` `Run this rule set..` `Open`

Expand the `Performance` section - for CA 1815 you can select whether you want this to be a warning, an error or none.

[image]

Comment: I agree that It should be a warning, however I am looking at the message right now, and it clearly says Error:
"MSBUILD : error : CA1815 : Microsoft.Performance : 'GenericSendRequest' should override Equals."

I am using VS2010, maybe it changed to an error from previous versions?

Answer (score 3):

You got a little lost in the IDE somehow, this is not a compiler error.  It is a code analysis error, performed by a tool known as FxCop.  You can disable it with Analyze + Configure, untick the "Enable Code Analysis on Build" option.

The tool is a little naggy, its use is more as a reminder that you might have done something unwise.  Which in this case is pretty unlikely, this is not the kind of struct you can meaningfully compare without doing a lot of work.  It is a performance warning, the default equality comparer for a struct uses reflection and that's not very efficient.  But you'll make it a lot less efficient by implementing a correct version of Equals().

There is something else wrong, a struct in C# does not at all behave like a struct in C++.  It should only be used for simple values that can be easily copied, given that it is a value type.  You should make this a class instead.  Solves the analysis error too.

Comment: I guess making it into a class would fix it. It bothers me that I cannot use a simple struct just like in C++ when I need a simple container for values(including references "pointers"). That is why I made it a struct, simple return of values.

Comment: @RamonZarazua: The difference between struct and class in C# is fundamental (value vs reference type). There is nothing "heavy" about using a class, in reality you should very rarely have to use a struct